# Merge DataGrid ColumnHeaders

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I would like to merge two column-Headers. Before you go and mark this question as duplicate please read further. I don't want a super-Header. I just want to merge two column-headers. Take a look at image below:

[image]

Can you see two columns with headers **Mobile Number 1** **and Mobile Number 2**? I want to show there only 1 column header as **Mobile Numbers**.

Here is the XAML used for creating above mentioned dataGrid:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,10,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Ledgers}" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Customer Name" Binding="{Binding LedgerName}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="City" Binding="{Binding City}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Mobile Number 1" Binding="{Binding MobileNo1}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Mobile Number 2" Binding="{Binding MobileNo2}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Opening Balance" Binding="{Binding OpeningBalance}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**Update1:**

[image]

**Update2**

I have created a converter as follows:

```
public class MobileNumberFormatConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null && value != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
        {
            if (value.ToString().Length <= 15)
            {
                int spacesToAdd = 15 - value.ToString().Length;
                string s = value.ToString().PadRight(value.ToString().Length + spacesToAdd);
                return s;
            }

            return value.ToString().Substring(0, value.ToString().Length - 3) + "...";
        }

        return "";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I have used it in XAML as follows:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Mobile Numbers">
    <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat=" {0} {1}">
            <Binding Path="MobileNo1" Converter="{StaticResource mobileNumberFormatConverter}"/>
            <Binding Path="MobileNo2" Converter="{StaticResource mobileNumberFormatConverter}"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

The output I got:

[image]

**Update3:**

At last I got the desired output.

Here is the code for Converter:

```
public class MobileNumberFormatConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null && value != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
        {
            if (parameter.ToString().ToUpper() == "N")
            {
                if (value.ToString().Length <= 15)
                {
                    return value.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    return value.ToString().Substring(0, 12);
                }
            }
            else if (parameter.ToString().ToUpper() == "S")
            {
                if (value.ToString().Length <= 15)
                {
                    int spacesToAdd = 15 - value.ToString().Length;
                    string spaces = "";
                    return spaces.PadRight(spacesToAdd);
                }
                else
                {
                    return "...";
                }
            }
        }

        return "";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Here is my XAML:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Mobile Numbers">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding MobileNo1, Converter={StaticResource mobileNumberFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter=N}" />
                <Run Text="{Binding MobileNo1, Converter={StaticResource mobileNumberFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter=S}" FontFamily="Consolas"/>
                <Run Text="   " FontFamily="Consolas"/>
                <Run Text="{Binding MobileNo2, Converter={StaticResource mobileNumberFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter=N}" />
                <Run Text="{Binding MobileNo2, Converter={StaticResource mobileNumberFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter=S}" FontFamily="Consolas"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Mobile Numbers">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat=" {0} {1}" Converter="{StaticResource YourConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="MobileNo1"/>
                        <Binding Path="MobileNo2"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
  </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: I have tried that before asking this question. If Mobile Numbers have different no. of digits or incase customer is from out-country then his mobile number is to be saved with country code, then the number of digits will vary. In that case the output might look bad. For more see the Update1 in question.

Comment: It is working but it may look bad, well you want to have it adjusted?

Comment: Absolutely, use MultiConverter(deriving from IMultiValueConverter) to fulfill it. If your number does not contain country code then add two spaces or whatever, it will provide that all values in column will have the same length.

Comment: OK, I will try it and let you know if I am able to solve it or not :)

Comment: I have tried it but I was not successful. Please take a look at update2 in question.

Comment: Thanks for giving me right advice. I have solved the problem. I used consolas Font for only the non-visible spaces, as consolas has same width for for all characters. To see the complete solution, please see Update3 in question.